# Rescanning specific folders with Windows Indexing service

Tags: windows, service, indexing

I need to know if there is a way I can automate rescanning certain folders within Windows Indexing Service. Possibly through a batch file or something like that.  I have several hundred folders that need to be rescanned and I don't feel like manually right clicking and hitting rescan on each one.

Comment: When ***rescan*** is required for ***Indexing Service*** ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a VBS script that should work for you.  You could put this in a loop over your folder names.

```
Set objISAdm = CreateObject("Microsoft.ISAdm")
objISAdm.MachineName="MyServerName"
Set objCatAdm = objISAdm.GetCatalogByName("MyCatalog")
Set objScopeAdm = objCatAdm.GetScopeByPath("c:\FolderToReScan")
objScopeAdm.Rescan("TRUE")
```

In the last line, TRUE means do a full scan.  Change it to FALSE to do an incremental scan.

Here's a good source for [**Indexing Service script samples**](http://www.activexperts.com/activmonitor/windowsmanagement/adminscripts/disk/indexing/#EnumIndexServiceScopes.htm).

Comment: I tried this script.  It keeps bombing out with an application exception in ntdll.dll

Comment: What version of Windows are you using?

Comment: Also, did you try just my code first or did you add it to something else to run?  I don't get that error no matter what I change with my code.

Comment: XP.  Only thing  change was "MyServerName"  "MyCatalog" and "c:\FolderToRescan" to reflect the specifics of the system

Comment: Is the target system your XP machine or is it a remote host?  If remote, what's its OS?

Comment: I am remote desktopped into a machine and executing locally there.  It is xp as well

Comment: No, you shouldn't.  That script runs as-is on my XP box.

Comment: @Kevin did you tried again or using powershell or C# ?

Comment: Script about `MsIndexServer`: http://www.activexperts.com/network-monitor/scripts/powershell/msindexserver